# How to represent an uninitialized (aka null) Map in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, null

How does one represent null in scala for collections?

The equivalent for List's would be "Nil" and it would be represented as follows:

```
Nil.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
```

What is the equivalent for Maps?

**UPDATE**  The two working solutions that I am aware of, from experimenting as well as from the suggested solutions are "Map()"  and "null.asInstanceOf(Map[String,String])".  The Map() is not what I intended: i did not want an empty item but actually a non-existent one (aka null in java). I was already aware that Nil is only for Lists: it was intended to illustrate the flavor of entity I was searching for used by Map's. Using "null.asInstanceOf(..)" is not a scala-ish idiom.  It appears there are no equivalents for Map ..?

Comment: "i did not want an empty item but actually a non-existent one (aka null in java)" In this case, `Nil` isn't what you want for lists; it's an empty list, exactly the same as `List()` and `List.empty`.

Comment: That depends on what the receiving API expects.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your API can treat `Nil` and `null` as equivalent, but it can't treat `Nil` and an empty list differently (because `Nil` _is_ simply an empty list).

Comment: That's exactly my point: the receiving api may expect a null not an empty list.

Comment: If it expects null, you can't use `Nil`.

Comment: He's not kidding. A Nil is an empty list, not a null list. I think you want val m: Option[Map[String,String]] = None as suggested by dhg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nil` is just an empty `List`.  It is not related to `null` in any way.

Scala has `null`, just like Java, but it should almost always be avoided.

What is your actual goal?

Do you want an empty Map?

```
val m = Map[String,String]()
```

Or an empty mutable Map that can be added to?

```
val m = collection.mutable.Map[String,String]()
```

Or an `Option[Map]` that can be initialized later?

```
val m: Option[Map[String,String]] = None
```

Or actually a `null`?

```
var m: Map[String,String] = null
```

Answer (score 10):

The best way do to it is:

```
val x = Map.empty[String, String]
```

With a mutable map:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{ Map => MMap }

val y = MMap.empty[String, String]
```